# Fedex address validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

I am using rails 2.3.17, I have used fedex .

I have used the plugin https://github.com/kdonovan/fedex

I have a customer who has account in fedex. But while shipping from the site , I am getting the error as

```
Fedex address validation failed. Check address details. Error messages: MODIFIED_TO_ACHIEVE_MATCH. Delivery Point: UNAVAILABLE. Residential Status: BUSINESS
```

Any guess why this is happening ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
 address_request_details: AvenueStateOrProvinceCodeWICityWausauWebAuthenticationDetailUserCredentialPasswordhTJxEaH7fXDqYtNaPFsPIDAy6KeyXl4QkKWZbZpxhzaIVersionMajor2ServiceIdavalIntermediate0Minor0

    process_address_request: #<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x346dedc 
{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}HighestSeverity="SUCCESS" 
{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Notifications=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x346d4f0 

{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Severity="SUCCESS" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Source="wsi"> 

{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Version=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x3469bac {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}ServiceId="aval" 

{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Major="2" 

{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Intermediate="0" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Minor="0"> {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}ReplyTimestamp="2014-04-21T04:25:59.044-05:00" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}AddressResults=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x3464508 

{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}ProposedAddressDetails=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x3463f54 {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Score="58" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}

Changes="MODIFIED_TO_ACHIEVE_MATCH" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}ResidentialStatus="BUSINESS" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}
DeliveryPointValidation="UNAVAILABLE" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}Address=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x345f4b8 {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}StreetLines="1000 S 17TH AVE" 

{http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}City="WAUSAU" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}StateOrProvinceCode="WI" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}PostalCode="54401-5741" {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}CountryCode="US"> {http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2}RemovedNonAddressData="">>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the edit, FedEx is not returning an error - you are getting back SUCCESS.

MODIFIED_TO_ACHIEVE_MATCH is very common in a FedEx response - it means that the user entered an address which required some changes. Compare the original data to the response and determine if you want to overwrite it or keep as-is.  Alliteratively, many sites are coded to show the original address and the standardized address side by side so the user can "update" to the standardized version. Be aware that FedEx (and UPS) validation can be destructive at times.

Comment: yeah, for this I need to modify the validation a little bit. Neither customers always reporting they can not proceed further.